# Access custom directive with ViewChild / ContentChild

Tags: javascript, angular, initialization, angular-directive

I've been trying to access my custom directive I applied on an element by using `@ViewChild(CustomDirective)` or `@ContentChild(CustomDirective)`, respectively using the set variable for the first time in my `ngAfterViewInit` or `ngAfterContentInit` function.

However, neither of them worked.
At first, I thought that it was due to me loading some content from a webserver, but even after having set static variables, it doesn't work.

Here's what I have:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[det-insert]',
})
export class DetailedDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

And

```
... (importing + component stuff)
export class DetailedView implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(DetailedDirective) detView : DetailedDirective;
    constructor(...)
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        alert(detView);
    }
}
```

And the template:

```
<ng-template det-insert></ng-template>
```

However, the alert returns `undefined`.

And I have no clue as to why. Any ideas? I already looked through stackoverflow, but neither is my template obstructed by `*ngIf`, nor do I start using my queried directive before the proper "AfterXInit" function. I already tried switching ViewChild and AfterViewInit for ViewContent and AfterContentInit respectively, to no avail.

Comment: `<ng-template>` isn't added to the DOM, and therefore `DetailedDirective` can't be found. If you use `<div det-insert>` it will work

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I tried that and it still doesn't work... (Still outputs undefined. Also, my code is in no way different from the one above - I commented all differences out.) (I tried again with both ViewChild and ContentChild)

Comment: Did you add `DetailedDirective` to `declarations: []` of your module

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ... Oh my god. I hadn't. I'm so sorry for wasting your time like this... Thank you so much, though! Want to add it as "official" answer? Maybe someone will, like me, forget to add directives to the declaration array one day and stumble upon this thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add DetailedDirective to declarations: [] of your module

`<ng-template>` isn't added to the DOM, and therefore DetailedDirective can't be found. If you use `<div det-insert>` it will work

Comment: I don't think that is true.  The documentation suggests that you use `ng-template` for the specific reason that it doesn't "render any additional input." (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html#!#loading-components).  I'm having a problem where my `@ViewChild` is undefined when I'm trying to refer to it's `viewContainerRef`.

Comment: If my directive is in a different module, do I still have to declare the directive in the module where my template lives as well?

Comment: @JakeSmith I missed that the directive is supposed to be a structural directive. But still, it won't get added to the DOM. Only the `TemplateRef` can be injected to the directive itself for it to stamp it to the DOM.

Comment: No, if it's part of the same module, then add it to declarations, otherwise add the module to imports that declares it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue myself.  I created a separate module for various alert directives/components.  My alert directive was defined and declared in that alert module.  I was trying to use the directive in my app module, and in order to get this same example to work, you need to specify that the alert module `exports: [AppLevelAlertDirective]`.

You can still use `<ng-template yourDirective></ng-template>`, despite it not showing up in the DOM later.  This is captured well before the DOM is rendered.  Please see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html#!#loading-components

Comment: Just spent hours banging my head against the wall... Sure enough, the directive was no re-exported by my library's top module. Thanks @jake-smith